# Open web page with macOS Safari in different language

Tags: mac, safari, language, internationalization

Is it possible to make Safari open a web page in a different language without having to change the whole system language?

I need to test if the Angular translations come out right but changing system language every time is really annoying.

Comment: Translation plugin?

Comment: No, I don’t need to translate, just load the page as if the system language was different - but without actually changing the system language

Comment: Take a look at this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_language.asp. I would suggest JavaScript injection of some sort.

Comment: @Josh that property is read-only

Comment: Or change example.com/en/ to example.com/es

Comment: @Josh please read the question again

Comment: You want to change the language the website loads correct?

Comment: @Josh the default language of the browser. just like changing the macos system language, for example you set macos to spanish and you see everything in spanish. this, but limited to safari browser, so I don’t have to log out and log in on macos each time I have to test how a web page appears

Comment: If the the website loads in Spanish due to changing the website address or the navigator.language vs changing the system language what’s the difference?

Comment: @Josh let me say this again: 
- navigator.language is a read-only property
- this is a web page of mine, it doesn't have /en and /es etc. because I did not implement them: it reacts to the default language of the browser. 
the question is: is it possible to change that language and not the whole system language?
If you don't know the answer or the scope of the question, please don't comment, thanks.

Comment: How does it change the language? JavaScript or a new page?

Comment: @Josh javascript (it's angular ngx-translate actually)

Comment: Ohhhhh. Gotcha.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure it's possible to independently change Safari’s accept-language, but try this terminal command, replacing ’en-AU’ depending on what language you would like:

```
/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari -AppleLanguages '(en-AU)'
```

You should be able to do it with Firefox, via Preferences/General/Language

Comment: Thanks, I did not try that safari "hack" yet, I'm a bit afraid of messing things up ;) but Firefox did the trick. 
I'll wait if someone comes up with a little less hacky solution for Safari otherwise I will accept this.

Comment: That would still change the whole Safari language. Not specifically asked for in the original post, but the idea would be to set the preferred language per website. I'm looking for that option right now.